# how to create appropriate branch for this case

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Let's say I am working on 2 tasks. I created one branch for task1_base and one branch for task1_work. task1_base branch will not change and task1_work will change. I finished the changes on task1_work and committed. Now I need work on task2. So i created one branch task2_base and task2_work, both of which are based on task1_work. I finished change on task2_work and committed. Now things are getting more complicated: I realize I have to make more changes on task1_work branch so i make the change and committed. Since my task2_work depends on the changes on task1_work, i will rebase task2_work on to task1_work. But what about task2_base? I tried to rebase it on to task1_work but couldn't because there was no commit on task2_base branch. I had to use Merge function. But Merge will make the history not clean. Is there a way to rebase work2_base on to work1_work?

Answer (score 0):

You should just move the branch (pointer) to task1_work:

```
git branch -f task2_base task1_work
```

*However*, the question that is ringing in my mind is: Why are you keeping those *base* branches in the first place?

Comment: the base branch is for code review. For example, once I commit my change in task2_work branch, the reviewer can review my change based on the difference between task2_work and task2_base. Does this make sense?

Comment: Actually i just tried the command: git branch -f task2_base task1_work, but it didn't work as expected. The change i made in task1_work didn't show up in task2_base. So we will have to do a merge?

Comment: that makes no sense. right after running that specific command, task1_wok and task2_base point to exactly the same revision.

Comment: If they point to the same revision so they will have the same content, right? But after i ran the command, i saw the change in task1_work but didn't see the change in task2_base.

Comment: are they pointing to the same revision? what it the output of `git rev-parse task1_work task2_base`? it should be the same revision id